# Xlxwriter header style

Tags: pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm using the following approach to generate a custom header for my excel file. 
When this is run in Jupyter Note book the header gets properly generated but when executed as a ".py" file the header formats are missing. I'm the same version of python and xlsxwriter for both execution

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
import pandas.io.formats.excel

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(30, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer,index=False)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None

header_format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True,
                                     'font_size':11,
                                     'bold': True,
                                     'align': 'center',
                                     'valign': 'top',
                                     'fg_color': '#D7E4BC',
                                     'border': 1})

worksheet.set_row(0,40, header_format)

workbook.close()
writer.save()
```

Comment: Do you have the same version of Pandas in both environments? The `pandas.io.formats.excel` variable changed in recent versions of Pandas.

Comment: `openpyxl` is another Excel writer that is very similar. This module was not impacted by the new pandas version as my packages run the same.

Comment: I have only one version of python in my machine python 2.7.13 , xlsxwriter 0.9.6
Pandas 0.20.1